# Using Tuple in VS2017, build failed but show no Error

Tags: c#, tuples, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

```
var range = (first: 1, end: 10);
```

When I build the project, there is no error in Error List window.
but the output window writes:

> 1>....cs(41,38,41,39): error CS1026: ) expected
>
> 1>....cs(41,40,41,41): error CS1001: Identifier expected
>
> 1>....cs(41,40,41,41): error CS1002: ; expected
>
> 1>....cs(41,41,41,42): error CS1002: ; expected
>
> 1>....cs(41,41,41,42): error CS1513: } expected
>
> ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

[image]
Only when I remove the code `var range = (first: 1, end: 10);` can this project build success.

By the way, I'm using .NET Framework 4.6.2 (not .Net Core) and I've installed the package `System.ValueTuple`

Comment: Could you post a minimal, complete, set of code that exhibits this behaviour, please?

Comment: What is the version of c# for the project?

Comment: Well, I have tested exact same code in a Console app with .NET Framework 4.5 and 4.6.2 with no errors. Idk if it's related but what's the Nuget package version that you have installed?

Comment: Are you running a Windows 10 insider build?

Comment: I am having the same issue using another new C# 7 feature:
    Int64.TryParse(stringValue, out Int64 intValue)
This should automatically declare and initialize the intValue variable without having to have a line for 'Int64 intValue;' before the TryParse. I am seeing the exact same issue. No error in error list, but the following in output: "error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected"
Using Visual Studio 2017, default C# version in Project Properties->Build->Advanced,  but /langversion:7 in .config file, System.CodeDom section for C#-compiler.

Comment: Those errors occur when compiling C# 7.0 code on a C# 6 compiler. Tuples and out vars produce syntax errors.

Comment: Solved. Thanks to @Kjetil

Comment: Assuming this was an ASP.NET Core, it would be worth stating that (and where this code "lives") - because the accepted answer is definitely not needed for class library / console projects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved this issue by updating the package Microsoft.Net.Compilers (to version 2.x.x) and changing /langversion in the config file (web.config/app.config) to 7:

```
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:7 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

Comment: Are you sure your answer solves the issue stated in original post? Or does it solve your own problem that you commented on before? Which should have been a separate post, rather than a comment btw.

Comment: I posted it as a comment because I believe me and the original poster faced the same issue. I tried to supplement David Arno and VMAtm with answers to their questions about version and minimal amount of code. The fact that you were not able to reproduce this with a console application, and neither were I, pointed me further to the conclusion that I most probably had the same issue as the original poster.

Comment: Yes, it works for me.  My original version of Microsoft.Net.Compilers was 1.3.2, and I updated it to 2.0.1, and changed web.config as Kjetil shows. This time all build succedd.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it got fixed by simply updating all NuGet packages.